# Elegant way to add a value to a class variable in java

Tags: java

I have a class say `Student`

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int score;
}
```

Assume I have all getter/setters.

Currently, I have an object of the student class say `std` which is having score value as 50.
I want to add 10 to the score in this object.

I can do this by below code:

```
std.setScore(std.getScore() + 10);
```

I am looking for an elegant way to write the same in which I don't use both getter and setter and can just increment the score by 10 or even by 1. 
Say by using ++ or something like +=10 etc.

Comment: add another method `incrementBy`? but I have no idea what this saves you, if anything at all

Comment: create an `incrementBy(int)` method.

Comment: Since these prerequisites do not look like an actual encapsulation, you can simply make `score` a `public` field without changing anything. Then, you can write `std.score += 10;`

Comment: What does this have to do with java-8 in particular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a method:

```java
public void incrementScore(int amount) {
  score += amount;
}
```

Is a negative increment allowed? If not, check it:

```java
/**
 * Increments the score by the given amount.
 *
 * @param amount the amount to increment the score by; must not be negative
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the amount is negative
 */
public void incrementScore(int amount) {
  if (amount < 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("The increment must not be negative.");
  }
  score += amount;
}
```

This approach is more elegant than using `get`/`set` because:

- it allows you to check the argument agains *business* rules,
- it adds a *business* method with a name that reveals intention.
- it allows you to write JavaDoc comments that describe the exact behaviour  of the operation

Comment: how would it make things better?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Better than using `std.setScore(std.getScore() + 10);`? What about error checking? And what do you think about intention revealing names?

Comment: @LutzHorn I think you are polluting the class Student with the method that doesn't really belong to it.  If we had `restoreScore()`, `doubleScore()`, `validateScore()` would you still put them into this class?

Comment: @LutzHorn it doesn't feel like a good OO approach. Neither `student.incrementScore(1)` nor `student.restoreScore()` looks right. The class `Student` does what it isn't supposed to do. Imagine you had 2-3 such fields with a few operations for each - the class would become a mess.

Comment: @LutzHorn I believe `student.getScore().increment(1)` is a nicer way. Yes, it introduces a new class, but it keeps `Student` clear and free of the responsibilities it shouldn't have. (I might be wrong, of course)

Comment: Good idea. Mabe worth an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As sugested in the comments you can create a new method on the student class.

```
public class Student {
   private String name;
   private int score;

   public void incrementScore(int increment){
       this.score = this.score + increment;
   }
}
```

And then call it on the std instance:

> std.incrementScore(10)